# Reveal what I really am

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Below is my passport photo, but it is not what it seems. It doesn't meet the requirements at all. Find the hidden picture, to make it valid.

> **FIND ALL THE 7ETT3RS AND NUM6ERS IN THIS HINT**

Use the following formula:

> B32 mod 11 * 25 = R/G/B

[image]

Comment: 736? That must be it!

Answer (score 11):

First, we separate the red, green, and blue channels of the image:

> [image] [image] [image]
> In the red we can see a C in the bottom right, the green an O in the bottom left, and the blue a W in the middle.

Now we use the formula, B32 mod 11 * 25 = R/G/B:

> Noticing that the left-hand side of the formula is always a multiple of 25 and that in the given image all the RGB pixel values are also multiples of 25, that suggests that for the right-hand side of the equation we want to use the R, G, or B values.
> B32 suggests the [Base32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) encoding method; according to that encoding, C is 2, O is 14, and W is 22. (This is confirmed by the characters used in the "HINT" text: Base32 encoding uses capital letters and the digits 2 through 7.) Plugging these into the left side of the equation then gives us 50 = R, 75 = G, and 0 = B. If we mark all the pixels where either the red value is 50, the green value is 75, or the blue value is 0, we reveal the face of our mysterious passport applicant:
>  [image]

Comment: You were totally right, but unfortunately I made a programming mistake. I should have double checked it :( The blue 0 is 'falsy', so it's overwritten by some random numbers. Didn't thougt of that.. I will fix it asap.

Comment: I have fixed it :)

Comment: @Lezzup Excellent! Answer updated :)

Comment: Good job finding the final picture! However, you made a shortcut determining the 3 letters, didn't foresee that was possible.. The function should also be used to clearly identify the letters. Please try that as well to have a complete answer

Comment: @Lezzup I'm away from the computer for a couple days, I'll have to try it when I return!

Comment: Did you had a change to look at it?

Comment: @Lezzup I've tried for a bit and although I can reverse engineer the RGB values we want to highlight I'm not sure how to get those from the hint; maybe someone else could take a look and see what I'm missing

Comment: basically the same process as what you did with the final 3 letters. But only then, instead of the 3 letters, use the distinct letters and digits from the hint. And look at the R, G and B values seperately.

Comment: @Lezzup *Every* one of them? No offense, but that seems like overkill. I have a Java app specifically designed for parsing RGB values in images, though... I'll take a try!